# How can I type annotate a general nested TypedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, typeddict

I'm trying to remove the `Any` type hint from code similar to the following:

```
from typing import TypedDict, Any


class NestedDict(TypedDict):
    foo: str


class EventDict(TypedDict):
    nested: NestedDict


class BaseEventDict(TypedDict):
    nested: Any # this should accept NestedDict but also other TypedDicts which may contain additional fields


test_dict: EventDict = {
    "nested": {"foo": "abc"},
}


def print_dict(source_dict: BaseEventDict):
    print(source_dict)


print_dict(test_dict)
```

Since the `nested` field can contain either `NestedDict` or other `TypedDict`s with additional fields (for other `EventDict`s), I've not been able to come up with a compatible `TypedDict` (`mypy` complains about extra keys). I thought `Mapping[str, object]` might work in `Any`'s place, since [[A]ny TypedDict type is consistent with Mapping[str, object]](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency). However, `mypy` complains with `Argument 1 to "print_dict" has incompatible type "EventDict"; expected "BaseDict"`. Is there anything I can use instead of `Any`, which essentially disables the check? Also, any insights into why `Mapping[str, object]` is not a valid type here?

Comment: `Mapping[str, object]` (or even `Mapping[Any, Any]` - no matter) is not a valid type, because TypedDict keys behave invariantly (first "discussion" paragraph under your PEP link). That means nothing except *exactly* TypedDict with `nested` field of type `Mapping[str, object]` can be compatible with `BaseEventDict` - that's due to mutability (it should be safe to assign e.g. `collections.Counter[str]` value to `BaseEventDict.nested` field defined as Mapping - and it certainly breaks your expectations).

Comment: Does [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=1b83d4a7e640ced593df600a2596dd79) work for you? You can use `_T` bound to `Mapping[str, object]` to allow any dicts instead of `NestedDict`-compatible only.

Comment: Ooh, amazing - that does work indeed! Not the most obvious syntax for a `TypedDict` that can be extended with additional fields, but it makes sense and certainly does the trick 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypedDict` fields are invariant, because `TypedDict` is a mutable structure. The reasoning behind that is explained in [PEP589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency) in detail. So, to accept a `TypedDict` with a field of type "some `TypedDict` or anything compatible with it" you can use a generic solution:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypedDict, Generic, TypeVar

class NestedDict(TypedDict):
    foo: str

_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=NestedDict)

class BaseEventDict(Generic[_T], TypedDict):
    nested: _T # this should accept NestedDict but also other TypedDicts which may contain additional fields
```

`BaseEventDict` is parametrized with a type of its field, which is bound to `NestedDict` - this way `T` can be substituted only with something compatible with `NestedDict`. Let's check:

```
class GoodNestedDict(TypedDict):
    foo: str
    bar: str

class BadNestedDict(TypedDict):
    foo: int


class EventDict(TypedDict):
    nested: NestedDict

class GoodEventDict(TypedDict):
    nested: GoodNestedDict
    
class BadEventDict(TypedDict):
    nested: BadNestedDict


# Funny case: lone TypeVar makes sense here
def print_dict(source_dict: BaseEventDict[_T]) -> None:
    print(source_dict)

test_dict: EventDict = {
    "nested": {"foo": "abc"},
}
good_test_dict: GoodEventDict = {
    "nested": {"foo": "abc", "bar": "bar"},
}
bad_test_dict: BadEventDict = {
    "nested": {"foo": 1},
}

print_dict(test_dict)
print_dict(good_test_dict)
print_dict(bad_test_dict)  # E: Value of type variable "_T" of "print_dict" cannot be "BadNestedDict"  [type-var]
```

In this setup `print_dict` is also interesting: you cannot use an upper bound, because the field type is invariant, so a single `TypeVar` with a bound (same as before) comes to rescue. Anything compatible with `NestedDict` is accepted as `_T` resolver, and everything incompatible is rejected.

Here's a [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=1b83d4a7e640ced593df600a2596dd79) with this implementation.